# Trying to block Agar.io android app connection on wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, android, blocking, ports

I want to block access to `Agar.io` completely from android devices in the house, my internet is through virgin media with a SuperHub, I've played with port blocking(ports 443 and 1501-1551) and domain blocking settings but no results...

I've thought about MAC address blocking but it's a last resort, is there any other way I could let's say block access to `agar.io` completely for a few hours a day?

Blocking all EU server IPs separately would be extremely time consuming as there is a lot of them.

Any suggestions and solutions are welcome.

Comment: I think blocking IPs is going to be the only way with your current setup.